# How to get value from tinymc editor in react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, textarea, editor, contenteditable

I'm trying to render data from the `tinyms` editor it was showing undefined in console using react *js*. I want to write some content to the `tinyms` editor using react *js*. Please help me with this problem..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';

class AddEvent extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            content: '',

        };
          this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
          this.handleEditorChange=this.handleEditorChange.bind(this.content);

    }
 render() {
        return (
       <form>
            <Editor
       initialValue="<p>This is the initial content of the editor</p>"
        init={{ plugins: 'link image code',
      toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic| alignleft aligncenter alignright | code'
                                    }}
         onChange={this.handleEditorChange}
                                />

      <div className="col-md-3">
  <button className="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Save Event</button>
                            </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function binding is like `.bind(this)` but you are binding `handleEditorChange` with incorrect value

Change

```
 this.handleEditorChange = this.handleEditorChange.bind(this.content);
```

To

```
 this.handleEditorChange = this.handleEditorChange.bind(this);
```

Please find below corrected code with additional changes as well. This would work as expected

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';

class AddEvent extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            content: '',

        };
          this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
          this.handleEditorChange=this.handleEditorChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleEditorChange(e){
        console.log('Content was updated:', e.target.getContent());
        this.setState({content: e.target.getContent()});
      }
 render() {
        const content = <p>This is the initial content of the editor</p>;
        return (
       <div>
         <form>
            <Editor
        initialValue={content}
        init={{ plugins: 'link image code',
        toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic| alignleft aligncenter alignright | code'}}
         onChange={this.handleEditorChange}/>

      <div className="col-md-3">
  <button className="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Save Event</button>
       </div>
    </form>
 </div>
)}
}
```

Comment: this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this); As you observe here if Im giving like this this.handleEditorChange=this.handleEditorChange.bind(this); it was showing undefined in the console.

Comment: But the content was coming in html tags...How to remove that html tags..Can You please help me with this problem..@Think-Twice

Comment: @AvinashMaddala I have updated my answer please give a try now. Since you have accepted my answer kindly do upvote

Comment: Yeah I agreed with your answer but I want another help data is still coming in html tags..I want it like proper content.

Comment: @AvinashMaddala Please render it without html tags.

Comment: Like initialValue="This is the initial content of the editor"